# Sybase SQL: Obtaining Sum over max

Tags: sybase

Sorry, this problem is so unique I couldn't figure out a better title.

I have a table in following form:

```
--------EXAMPLE---------------------------------------------------------
Cat1           Cat2          Value
a              e1            113
b              e1            14
a              e2            15
c              e3            13
a              e1            13
a              e2            11
c              e4            1
```

For each distinct value in Cat1, I want to find maximum of Values grouped by Cat2 and then sum them up.

So, for above table for Cat1 = 'a'

Step 1:
I want to extract the following rows:

```
Cat1           Cat2          Value
a              e1            113
a              e2            15
a              e1            13
a              e2            11
```

Step 2:
I want to extract maximum corresponding to Cat2:

```
Cat1           Cat2          Value
a              e1            113
a              e2            15
```

Step 3:
Sum the Value to obtain:

```
Cat1           SumOfValueColumn
a              128
b              14
c              14
```

I can do the above in multiple steps but I want to achieve it in one step. I am using Sybase.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

-- Create a view which does not use up any more database space.

```
create view max_cat_tbl_view
( Cat1, Cat2, Maxvalue ) as 
select Cat1, Cat2, max(Value) 
from cat_tbl 
group by Cat1, Cat2
go
```

-- Query the view to get sum over max

```
select Cat1, sum(Maxvalue) from max_cat_tbl_view group by Cat1 order by Cat1
go
```

Good SQL, good night.
kelley805

Answer (score 0):

-- The previous answer could have been done in one step by removing the go in the middle.
-- Here is another answer using Sybase temporary tables

```
select Cat1, Cat2, max(Value) Maxvalue
into   #max_cat_tbl
from   cat_tbl
group by Cat1, Cat2  order by 1, 2
select Cat1, sum(Maxvalue) from #max_cat_tbl group by Cat1 order by Cat1
drop table #max_cat_tbl
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:-

SELECT cat1,sum(Value) as sum_Value FROM
         (SELECT cat1,cat2,max(Value) as Value FROM #tmp1  group by cat1,cat2 ) d1
 GROUP BY cat1